# WCF RIA Getting Large Data Faster

Tags: silverlight-4.0, wcf-ria-services

I have a Silverlight Client(4.0) calling a WCF RIA Service method which returns a large set of Data.The method returns a List where CustomObject has around 20 fields.

What i noticed is that it's extremely slow when the number of items in that list is 20,000.
If i put a break point on the return statement in the server and put one break point on the Client side, i can see its taking at least 40 seconds, to hit the break point on the client side once it returns the list from the server.I am wondering why is it taking so much time to bring the data from the server to the client.

Is it normal with WCF RIA services ? Is there any way to increase the efficiency,

Thanks !

Comment: Are you getting the data through a load operation?  or invoke operation?

Comment: 20000 records are too much to expect faster download. You have to implement paging(which is easy with DomainCollectionView) and you have to create a DTO class to bring only properties you need.

Answer (score 0):

Well, 20.000 records are...  20.000 records.  The lengthy download is not an uncommon issue in a scenario like this. You might do two things:

1. Page the records.
2. Ask WCF to compress the data. Not really sure if this is possible as Silverlight does not uses the full WCF functionality.

Comment: just checking, did you mean common or uncommon?  It looks like you meant to write 'uncommon'.

Comment: Is Compression possible with WCF RIA ? If you could send me any links that would be great ! I think i tried RadCompression with Telerik and didnt seem to work.

Comment: I'm not the best with WCF, but check this post: http://forums.silverlight.net/t/204790.aspx/1